# Efficiently modify the combined probability of many independent events as variable values change (simulation model)

Tags: algorithm, combinations, netlogo, probability, modeling

**CONTEXT**

I need to combine the probability of occurrence of many thousands of events for millions of individuals (trees) in an agent-based/individual-based simulation model developed in NetLogo (agent-based simulation) and Go (to parallelize probability calculations). For those interested, the probabilities are for infection events that result from multiple other events, e.g., exposure, transmission, each with their own probabilities, for individual trees in a forested landscape.

Each individual can potentially be infected by thousands of other individuals in its surroundings. The full model includes millions of individuals, and so I am designing the model to calculate, modify, and update probabilities as quickly and efficiently as possible as conditions in the simulation change.

Based on the probability math that, if [image] and [image] are events that are **independent** and **not mutually exclusive** and occur with different probabilities [image] and [image], with the overall probability [image] calculated as:

[image]

or

[image]

In addition, each event probability [image] is the product of two other probabilities [image] and [image], where [image] is constant across events but [image] differs between events).

Therefore, the overall equation used in my model to calculate **each** individual tree's **probability of infection** [image] by any other individual (i.e., combining probability of many such infection events) is as follows:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Over time in the simulation, the value of [image] for a given individual tree will change (depending on changing state variables of the individual trees) while the values of [image] remain constant. Therefore, as the value of [image] changes between time steps, the value of [image] will need to be modified to reflect this change.

However, given the amount of values involved in the calculation (thousands of calculations for each of millions of individual trees), it is not practical to store each value of [image] for each individual (tree) once the (maybe not possible given the constraints of the software and computing resources I am using). In addition, I want to limit the amount of infomation that passes back and forth between NetLogo (which stores the states and probabilities for each individual) and Go (where probabilities are calculated but not stored) to avoid exceeding memory constraints?

Rather than recalculate the overall probability from scratch, which requires lots of time and computing resources, I want to be able to modify the overall probability [image]
for a given individual tree based on the change in the value of [image].

**QUESTIONS**

***What is a generalized form for calculating the probability that at least one event occurs given N independent events with different probabilities given the criteria above?***

***How can I efficiently implement the modification of each individual's probability of infection without having to re-calculate from scratch?***

*For example, can I rearrange the equation to isolate [image] so that I can calculate the probability of the event at time [image] based on its probability at time [image], as follows:[image]?*

p.s. also posted (different formats) at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717211/efficiently-modify-the-combined-probability-of-many-independent-events-when-vari and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714736/combining-and-modifying-many-probabilities-of-independent-non-mutually-exclusiv

Answer (score 0):

The correct update has a decidedly np-complete feeling about it.  A long line of research starting with http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~sayan/npcomplete.pdf has found that updating Bayesian networks for various purposes is NP-hard, which your exact model requires.

I strongly recommend that you either seek a simplified approximation, or use Monte-Carlo methods.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Would you mind elaborating on how I might use Monte-Carlo methods or provide a reference or resource? I have little background in that area.

As for the complexity of the issue, I have a working version that is fast enough that simply sums the probabilities (and therefore overestimates by not subtracting the combined terms, e.g., p1*p2. Therefore, if there's a mathematical solution that I find easy enough to implement (which is where I am struggling), I feel that the approach I'm taking currently may still be tenable. Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Flow What you do is run multiple simulations where upon exposure a tree does or does not get infected.  Then from a series of simulations, you estimate the probabilities of trees being infected.  Sum them up, and you get your estimated answer.

Comment: Where the approach that you are thinking of is going to run into trouble is tracking through "If this tree gets sick, then that starts spreading, after five stages of infection, which combinations of 10 trees now have correlated probabilities by virtue of possibly having being infected along different paths from this common ancestor?"  In the end with `n` trees you will wind up with `2^n` subsets with some correlation term that plays into things.

Comment: I think I understand this last point. Follow-up:

1. I don't care about the specific source of infection (not concerned with the 'common ancestor' for infection, which does not need to be tracked), only about the prob of infection from ANY tree within the infection distance. Does that change things?

Comment: 2. Regardless of the implementation, do you know how to address the first, mathematical question I asked: _"What is a generalized form for calculating the probability that at least one event occurs given N independent events with different probabilities given the criteria above?"_

Comment: @Flow If the events are independent, then `P(event)` is `1 - product((1 - P_i))` where the `P_i` are the odds of the independent events.  That said, in a spreading epidemic, the odds of nearby trees being infected at the same time are strongly correlated with each other.  Which means that you need to be dealing with the probabilities of specific sets of trees being infected at the same time - and that is where the combinatorial explosion of combinations kills you.

Comment: Regarding your last response and independent of the implementation: in the generalized equation, if `p_i` consists of `p_a` and `p_b,i`, where `p_a` is the same for all events but `p_b,i` is different for each event, is there a way to isolate out `p_a` so that when `p_a` changes I can simply modify the previously calculated probability? Such that the probability of the event at time `t` is a function of the prob of the event at time `t-1` and the values of `p_a` at times `t` and `t-1`? In other words `P(event)_t ( P(event)_t-1; p_a,t; p_a,t-1)`

Comment: @Flow I don't think so.  In the general equation for non-independent events, the probability of getting infected in a period of time is the probability of not starting being infected, plus the probability of being infected by any neighboring tree minus the probability of being infected by any pair of neighboring trees plus the probability of being infected by any 3 neighboring trees and so on.  If the period is small enough, then you can ignore the higher order terms.  BUT independence continues to not be true...

Comment: The odds of this tree and its neighbors being infected are strongly correlated.  As are the odds of one neighbor tree being infected while a neighbor is infected.  Any simplification that tries to ignore these correlations will be highly inaccurate.  THAT SAID, using Monte Carlos you can estimate how strong these correlations are in general, then use that for a simplified analytical model.  But getting this correct requires working with a statistician.  I would not trust myself to get it right.

Comment: My understanding of the Monte Carlo method is limited, but, if I am not mistaken, my model does to some degree operate based on a monte carlo method. Not sure if that changes your most recent responses. @btilly

The model as it stands now calculates a tree's probability of infection as a function of their distance from infected trees during a given time step.
Because trees that are close together are at similar distances from infected trees, yes, the probabilities are highly correlated.

Comment: As I think you are suggesting, one issue with my approach is that each tree's probability of infection is not an input in the equation to its neighbor's probabilities of infection, is that correct?
In the simulation, after the probabilities are calculated, a "coin flip" happens for each tree to determine whether or not it becomes infected based on its probability of infection. (in reality, it's not a coin flip but rather a random floating point number is drawn from a uniform distribution from 0 to 1 and compared to the probability). This is the part that to me seems like a Monte Carlo method

Comment: In contrast to your second to last comment, there's no probability that the tree starts as infected or not infected, because each tree is either infected or not infected at any given point in time in the simulation.

Comment: Finally, I would add that my intention is to run this simulation many times with different sets of conditions to get an understanding of how trends in infection are influenced by environmental conditions. I am applying these calculations to realistic but hypothetical tree-filled landscapes. I am interested in using individual-tree-scale calculations to discover emergent, larger-scale trends as is often the intention of individual-based models. I consider the outputs to inherently be approximations and don't focus on the fate of specific trees.

Comment: @Flow If you're running a simulation where each tree is infected or not at any given point in time, you update by taking each uninfected tree and seeing whether it survived not infected by each infected neighbor.  Then you need to run the scenario multiple times to get a sense of how much chance plays into the progression.